# Why does my page look fine on Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple webpage that I'm working on and it looks fine on Chrome but when I open it it with Firefox it displays the page in a weird way. I'm using Bootstrap with some custom CSS. Does anyone know why this is? Here is my code (the page has more rows but I cut some so it wouldn't be too long).

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Search For Recipes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="food.js"></script>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="title">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h1>Search for Recipes by Ingredients or by Dish</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img src="./images/fork.png" alt="Fork and knife">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form-container">
            <form>
                <label class="visuallyhidden" for="ingredients">Separate Ingredients by Comma (chicken, rice,
                    carrots)</label>
                <input type="text" id="ingredients" name="ingredients"
                    placeholder="Separate Ingredients by Comma (chicken, rice, carrots)...">
            </form>
            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="recipe_choice">Choose by Ingredients or by Dish</label>
            <select id="recipe_choice">
                <option value="by_ingredient">By Ingredients</option>
                <option value="by_dish">By Dish</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5"></div>
            <button id="button" class="col-2" onclick="returnResult()">Search</button>
            <div class="col-5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="subtitle" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h2>What Are you Hungry For?</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loading" style="display: none;">
            <div class="spinner-border"></div>
            <h1>Analyzing Taste Buds...</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="error" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h2>Oops Something Went Wrong :/ Please Try Again </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="recipe-grid" class="container" style="display: grid;">
            <div class="row" id="row1">
                <div id="recipe1" class="recipe-container col-md"><img class="img-fluid"
                        src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/1003525-556x370.jpg"><br>
                    <div class="recipe_link"><a href="https://thewoksoflife.com/2018/05/dace-fish-black-beans-rice/">One
                            Pot Rice Cooker Rice with Dace Fish</a></div>
                    <p id="recipe_info1">One Pot Rice Cooker Rice with Dace Fish is a <b>gluten free, dairy free, and
                            pescatarian</b> main course. For <b>$1.26 per serving</b>, this recipe <b>covers 16%</b> of
                        your daily requirements of vitamins and minerals. One portion of this dish contains roughly
                        <b>17g of protein</b>, <b>2g of fat</b>, and a total of <b>407 calories</b>. This recipe serves
                        4. 3 people found this recipe to be flavorful and satisfying. A mixture of rice, sugar,
                        scallion, and a handful of other ingredients are all it takes to make this recipe so
                        scrumptious. It is brought to you by The Woks of Life. From preparation to the plate, this
                        recipe takes around <b>30 minutes</b>. All things considered, we decided this recipe <b>deserves
                            a spoonacular score of 57%</b>. This score is solid. Similar recipes include <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/crock-pot-fish-stew-rice-94006">Crock Pot Fish Stew
                            &amp; Rice</a>, <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/perfectly-cooked-coconut-jasmine-rice-without-a-rice-cooker-602531">Perfectly
                            Cooked Coconut Jasmine Rice without a Rice Cooker</a>, and <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/rice-cooker-caribbean-style-chicken-rice-pilau-33295">Rice
                            Cooker Caribbean-style Chicken Rice Pilau</a>.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="recipe2" class="recipe-container col-md"><img class="img-fluid"
                        src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/666075-556x370.jpg"><br>
                    <div class="recipe_link"><a href="http://www.taste.com.au/recipes/15297/easy+fried+rice">Easy fried
                            rice</a></div>
                    <p id="recipe_info2">The recipe Easy fried rice is ready <b>in roughly 40 minutes</b> and is
                        definitely a spectacular <b>gluten free and dairy free</b> option for lovers of Chinese food.
                        This recipe makes 4 servings with <b>296 calories</b>, <b>9g of protein</b>, and <b>9g of
                            fat</b> each. For <b>62 cents per serving</b>, this recipe <b>covers 12%</b> of your daily
                        requirements of vitamins and minerals. 1452 people have made this recipe and would make it
                        again. It works well as a very affordable side dish. If you have sunrice rice, vegetable oil,
                        eggs, and a few other ingredients on hand, you can make it. All things considered, we decided
                        this recipe <b>deserves a spoonacular score of 59%</b>. This score is good. Try <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/easy-fried-rice-577493">Easy Fried Rice</a>, <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/easy-fried-rice-643786">Easy Fried Rice</a>, and <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/easy-fried-rice-625318">Easy Fried Rice</a> for
                        similar recipes.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="row3">
                <div id="recipe3" class="recipe-container col-md"><img class="img-fluid"
                        src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/18144-556x370.jpg"><br>
                    <div class="recipe_link"><a
                            href="http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/rice-green-peas-shrimp-butter-50400000109570/">Rice
                            and Green Peas with Shrimp Butter</a></div>
                    <p id="recipe_info3">You can never have too many side dish recipes, so give Rice and Green Peas with
                        Shrimp Butter a try. One portion of this dish contains roughly <b>3g of protein</b>, <b>4g of
                            fat</b>, and a total of <b>140 calories</b>. This gluten free and vegetarian recipe serves 6
                        and costs <b>24 cents per serving</b>. Not a lot of people made this recipe, and 1 would say it
                        hit the spot. From preparation to the plate, this recipe takes around <b>45 minutes</b>. A
                        mixture of shrimp butter, carrot, thyme, and a handful of other ingredients are all it takes to
                        make this recipe so yummy. All things considered, we decided this recipe <b>deserves a
                            spoonacular score of 22%</b>. This score is not so tremendous. Try <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/inspiralized-rice-parmesan-squash-rice-risotto-with-asparagus-green-peas-gluten-free-563847">Inspiralized
                            Rice: Parmesan Squash Rice Risotto with Asparagus &amp; Green Peas (Gluten Free)</a>, <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/shrimp-croquettes-with-creamed-green-peas-770573">Shrimp
                            Croquettes with Creamed Green Peas</a>, and <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/shrimp-peas-and-rice-6146">Shrimp, Peas And Rice</a>
                        for similar recipes.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="recipe4" class="recipe-container col-md"><img class="img-fluid"
                        src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/666990-556x370.jpg"><br>
                    <div class="recipe_link"><a href="http://allrecipes.com/recipe/fried-rice-restaurant-style/">Fried
                            Rice Restaurant Style</a></div>
                    <p id="recipe_info4">Fried Rice Restaurant Style might be just the side dish you are searching for.
                        For <b>42 cents per serving</b>, this recipe <b>covers 8%</b> of your daily requirements of
                        vitamins and minerals. This recipe makes 8 servings with <b>237 calories</b>, <b>7g of
                            protein</b>, and <b>5g of fat</b> each. Head to the store and pick up enriched rice, eggs,
                        soy sauce, and a few other things to make it today. Plenty of people made this recipe, and 4305
                        would say it hit the spot. It is a good option if you're following a <b>gluten free, dairy free,
                            fodmap friendly, and vegetarian</b> diet. From preparation to the plate, this recipe takes
                        roughly <b>45 minutes</b>. This recipe is typical of Chinese cuisine. All things considered, we
                        decided this recipe <b>deserves a spoonacular score of 53%</b>. This score is solid. Try <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/how-to-cook-fried-chicken-maxs-restaurant-style-478402">How
                            to cook: Fried chicken, Max’s Restaurant style</a>, <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/restaurant-style-mexican-rice-513013">Restaurant Style
                            Mexican Rice</a>, and <a
                            href="https://spoonacular.com/recipes/restaurant-style-mexican-rice-666068">Restaurant Style
                            Mexican Rice</a> for similar recipes.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff189;
}
.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
#title{
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#subtitle{
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#error{
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#title h1{
    font-size: 3em;
}
#loading{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#loading div{
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#form-container {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2;
    grid-template-columns: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

select {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 3;
}
#form-container input {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 5vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}

#button {
    appearance: none;
    color: black !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #EC7357;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}
#recipe-grid{
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: none;
}
.recipe-container img{
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    border: solid #EC7357 3px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5% auto auto auto;
}
.recipe-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
background: #fff189;
box-shadow:  20px 20px 60px #d9cd74, 
             -20px -20px 60px #ffff9e;
    justify-self: center;
}

.recipe-container p{
    padding: 5%;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
.recipe_link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That's because mozilla firefox uses their own standards of css. take a look at the mozilla only css properties and adjust your code accordingly. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions

Comment: Thank You. I always thought browsers treated things like margin the same. Guess not really.